# Compare two Types

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a class looks quite like this:

```
object value;
Type type;
```

When I create the object I set the type to the type of the Object.

How can I compare this type with another type?

If for example the type is `String`:

```
type.Equals(String)
```

and

```
type == String
```

does not work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this context, you compare your `Type` instance with the result of `typeof(T)`, where `T` is the type you want to compare.

```
bool objectIsString = myType == typeof(string);
```

Comment: keyword "is" has now become a better option.

Comment: @jeancallisti It behaves differently, so it's not automatically "better". For instance, `derivedFromBaseInstance is Base` will return true, while `typeof(DerivedFromBase) == typeof(Base)` will return false.

Answer (score 2):

Check this might help you. Using **Object.GetType()**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
if(typeitem is string)
{
   // Your Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well this should work

```
bool isSameType = (value != null && value.GetType() == type);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Type.Equals()` requires that you also pass a Type.  Thus, turn the string into a type:

```
type.Equals(GetType(string))
```